How to programatically insert WPML translation for a custom string?
I'm trying to add translation for content that's stored within a custom table.
I do this by using the following snippet from the documentation:
do_action('wpml_register_string', 'custom string', 'string_name', [
    'kind' => 'Custom String',
    'kind_slug' => 'custom-string',
    'post_id' => 123,
    'title' => 'The String',
    'name' => 'string_name',
], 'My String', 'LINE');


Things are going well, the translation is picked into the ATE[1], all good.
However, this is a part of a system that will need some migration, therefore I'll need to insert few tens of thousands of translated strings, so doing it manually it's not an option.
What I'd also like to do is: given the string_name string defined above, how do I insert translation for that string and mark it as completed on ATE?
I've found some leads by stepping into the code, but I hope there is a slightly easier way than rebuilding half of the ATE 

Update:
I've managed to dig into the code and found this:
You register the string with the following code:
$package = [
    'kind' => "The Translation Package ({$postID})",
    'kind_slug' => "the-translation-package-{$postID}",
    'post_id' => $postID,
    'title' => 'My Package Title',
    'name' => 'my-package-name'
];

$stringValue = 'original string; can be anything here';

do_action(
    'wpml_register_string',
    $stringValue,
    'my-string-name',
    $package,
    'My String Title',
    'LINE' // or AREA if it's a multi-line
);

Then you can add the translation as follows:
$string_id = icl_get_string_id($stringValue, "{$package['kind_slug']}-{$package['name']}", 'my-string-name');
icl_add_string_translation($string_id, 'es', 'translation value', ICL_TM_COMPLETE);

This do work, so yay.
However, there are couple of more issues:

Although the string translation IS inserted, it doesn't appear to mark the post as translated
Although the translation is marked as ICL_TM_COMPLETE the UI doesn't seem to reflect this state.


[1]: advanced translation editor
